# Laravel public_path() return C:\wamp\www\ instead of C:/wamp/www

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
 $path = (public_path("images/") . $filename);

 echo $path;
```

> C:\wamp\www\jobpost\public\images/Person.PNG   //problem occur from this /

I want this path to access my picture

> C:\wamp\www\jobpost\public\images\Person.PNG //how i can do this

```
 (public_path("images\") . $filename); 
 //i add the slash like this error occur
```

Comment: `echo str_replace(chr(47),chr(92),$path);` using `ord` here, so no escape needed.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions or instead simply use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` to separate between the two paths;

Comment: PHP accepts both separators almost everywhere. What does "problem occur from this" mean exactly?

Answer (score 2):

you are providing `linux` directory separator , while you are in windows.

you may use the windows separator directly as follows:

```
$path = (public_path("images\\") . $filename);
```

or simply to make is safer you should use the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` pre-defined CONSTANT as follows:

```
$path = (public_path("images") . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename);
```

---

#### update

the issue with that:

```
(public_path("images\") . $filename);
```

is that you are escaping the double quotes while you need it to enclose your string parameter.

Comment: how can i create the link in json response. picture show directly in  postman with this  return response()->file($path);  means link shown in response when user click on this link than picture show ?? any idea how i do this

Comment: `response()->json([$path]);`